# je m'en doute! Je m'en serais douté! meanings

Tags: verbes-de-perception

I understand "se douter" means to have an idea, inkling about something. However, is "je m'en doute" the correct way of saying "I knew it"?

Also, does "Je m'en serais douté" mean "I could have told you" or "I should have known"?

It is a curious verb, "se douter", for English-speakers to get their head around.

Comment: Je m'en doute →I can imagine.  Je m'en serais douté → I thought as much.

Comment: "the correct way" is a little strong, "*je le savais*" is very common too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of meaning 'I'm not sure that it's true, I'm wondering', ***Je m'en doute*** means 'despite not knowing it for sure, I have no real doubt about it'.

***Je m'en serais douté*** is used when you are made aware of something to tell you aren't surprised by it because you were already suspecting it. The meaning is the first one you suggest: 'I could have told you'.

Comment: That clarifies it thank you. useful expressions!